# Call stack size exceeded after several clicks in a combobox

Tags: javascript, wcf, recursion, dojo, callstack

I'm have a combobox on a website built with Dojo and using the ArcGIS Javascript API.  Since the combobox can contain thousands of entries, I'm proceeding with paging, dispatching 25 entries at a time.

If the client clicks very quickly, in a very compulsive way, on the "More Results" displayed at the end of my 25 entries list, he ends up (after a few dozens of clicks) with an error.

- Chrome displays "RangeError : Maximum call stack size exceeded".
- Firefox gives "Internal Error : too much recursion".
- We have not been able to generate the issue on IE.

Closing the browser or emptying the cache does not help.  The IIS WCF service application pool needs to be recycled if any user wants to call a new request.

The combobox datastore is created within the widget as :

```
var cboValueDataStore = new com.<...>.data.IdsValuesQueryReadStore(
    {
        url: "proxy.ashx",
        requestMethod: "get",
        doClientPaging: false,
        url2: getValuesUrl
    }
);
```

The IdsValuesQueryReadStore class starts with

```
require(
    ["dojo/_base/declare", 
     "dojox/data/QueryReadStore", 
     "dojo/_base/lang", 
     "dojo/json", 
     "dojo/_base/array"], 
    function(declare, QueryReadStore, lang, json, array) {
        declare(
            "com.fujitsu.data.IdsValuesQueryReadStore", 
            QueryReadStore, 
            {
```

The IdsValuesQueryReadStore class contains these two functions that are called everytime the user clicks on "More results" :

```
fetch: function(request) {
    console.log("IdsValuesQueryReadStore : fetch");
    var pageNumber = Math.floor(request.start / request.count) + 1;
    request.serverQuery = {
        url: this.url2 + 
             request.query.where + 
             "&start=" + 
             pageNumber + 
             "&count=" + 
             request.count
    };
    return this.inherited("fetch", arguments);
},
```

and

```
_filterResponse: function(data) {   
    console.log("IdsValuesQueryReadStore : _filterResponse");        
    data = json.parse(data);            
    data.items = this._dataToItems(data[0]);
    data.numRows = data[1];    
    return data;
},
```

I have looked through the code for recursion errors, such as a function calling itself, but I can't find anything.

I have monitored the ressources while launching the bug, and there were no extraordinary charges on the CPU, the network, the disk or the memory.

I don't really know where to look now to solve the issue.  I have read about this case 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/765248/Resolve-Too-Much-Recursion-Error-when-Using-Jquery 
where an Event would propagate recursively between the Previous and Next buttons, and wondered if this couls be the case with the picklist paging...  But if so, I have no idea how to solve this!

Any clue, anyone?

***Edit #1 (2015-10-01) :***

I added some counters for the requests.  Every time the user clicks on "More results", the functions fetch and _filterResponses are called; therefore they should have the same count.  The console.log shows that _filterResponse is somehow slower then fetch.  I have something like

```
...
fetchCount = 220
fetchCount = 221
fetchCount = 222
filterResponseCount = 98
fetchCount = 223
filterResponseCount = 99
...
```

I wonder if changing some parameters in IIS such as the queue length could help?

***Edit #2 (2015-10-01) :***

I tried to slow down the fetch function this way :

```
fetch: function(request) {
    console.log("IdsValuesQueryReadStore : fetch");
    this.fetchCount++;
    console.log("fetchCount = ", this.fetchCount);
    this.sleep(1000);
    ...
},

sleep: function(miliseconds) {
    console.log("Go to sleep");
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
    }
    console.log("Wake up!");
},
```

By slowing down the fetch function, I saw that the fetchCount and the filterResponse count were closer, but the codes ends up crashing after about 100 clicks...

***Edit #3 (2015-10-06) :***

It seems we figured it out.  The problem was within our WCF code : some database connexions were not closed properly.  Every click on "More result" generated some unclosed connexions and it eventually exceeded the allowed limit.